# read command in zsh throws error

Tags: zsh, read

In zsh, running the command `read -p 'erasing all directories (y/n) ?'  ans`, throws the error,

```
read: -p: no coprocess
```

But in bash, it prints a prompt. How do I do this in zsh?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can still use `read`, you just need to print a prompt first. In `zsh`, `-p` indicates that input should be read from a coprocess instead of indicating the prompt to use.

You can do the following instead, which is POSIX-compliant:

```
printf >&2 '%s ' 'erase all directories? (y/n)'
read ans
```

Like for ksh/zsh's `read 'var?prompt'` or bash's `read -p prompt var`, the prompt is issued on stderr so as not to pollute the normal output of your script.

Comment: Why do you do `printf >&2 '%s '` instead of just `echo` ?

Comment: @Ken that emulates the behaviour of zsh to print the prompt to stderr. Using echo, it could be achieved with `echo -n >&2 'erase all directories? (y/n) '`

Answer (score 4):

or a more `zsh`-like way

```
() {
  local compcontext='yn:yes or no:(y n)'
  vared -cp 'erasing all directories (y/n) ? ' ans
}
```

Which allows completing the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Same as in `ksh`:

```
IFS= read -r 'ans?erasing all directories (y/n)? '
```

Also note that `zsh`'s `read` has the `-q` for yes/no answers:

```
if read -q '?erasing all directories (y/n)? '; then
  rm -rf -- *(D/)
fi
```

It returns true if your enter yes and doesn't require you to press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: It should be noted that `-q` will not output a trailing newline after the user's reply.  You need to do that yourself if you want one.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `read -q`. Exactly what I need.