# How can I make "Press any key to continue"

Tags: bash

I'm making a script to install my theme, after it finished installing it will appear the changelog and there will be "Press any key to continue" so that after users read the changelog then press any key to continue

Comment: use `less` to display your changelog

Comment: Ugh - don't do that!  Installers should not be interactive; nobody wants to sit babysitting when they could have a bunch of stuff queued up to install.  Just drop the changelog in your platform's standard location (usually `/usr/share/doc/<package>/Changelog`) and let them be done with it.  For those who want to read every change, they can just install `apt-showchanges` or equivalent...

Comment: Well in my country people do differently, so i just make theme installer as simple as possible: choose option to install>let script do it all>after finished installing show the changelog>press any key to exit, it just a script to install my iOS 10 theme on iPhone 3GS by replacing system. I double check the code so that it wont mess up the system, I tried a few install attempt and it works flawlessly

Comment: but... where's the "any" key? ;)

Comment: if i could edit my comment this late I'd say 'use less to display your changelog, but "Ugh - don't do that! ..."'

Comment: His other problem: the iPhone does not have any keys.

Comment: The onscreen keyboard of iPhone still work with "press any key to continue"

Comment: Interactive mode would be a useful addition to the command line arguments, just off by default.

Comment: I understand that you asked for a bash command, and I got here similar, but after learning about the (ugh) `read -n 1 -s -r -p` command I am convinced that we are most likely better off writing the script in python.

Answer (score 529, accepted):

You can use the `read` command. If you are using `bash`:

```
read -p "Press enter to continue"
```

In other shells, you can do:

```
printf "%s " "Press enter to continue"
read ans
```

As mentioned in the comments above, this command does actually require the user to press <kbd>enter</kbd>; a solution that works with any key in `bash` would be:

```
read -n 1 -s -r -p "Press any key to continue"
```

### Explanation by [Rayne](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/10938/rayne) and [wchargin](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/37380/wchargin)

`-n` defines the required character count to stop reading

`-s` hides the user's input

`-r` causes the string to be interpreted "raw" (without considering backslash escapes)

Comment: Then what after the `read` statement? Seems to be missing the following line.

Comment: this helped me when I ran into the "no coprocess" error in zsh https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198372/read-command-in-zsh-throws-error

Comment: If you got here because somebody integrated this into their code (for example `abook --add-email-quiet`), and you need a workaround, pipe `yes | thecommand`.

Comment: Yes, but I would add (like suggested by @EKons) to incl. ";echo" at the end, as it is more elegant, it brings the terminal back to a fresh new line. just my 2 cents

Comment: it's showing % when pressing key.

Answer (score 24):

```
read -rsn1 -p"Press any key to continue";echo
```

Or, if you actually need the `REPLY` variable:

```
read -rsn1 -p"Press any key to continue" variable;echo
```

Replace `variable` with a variable name you don't need.

Comment: `echo; read -rsn1 -p "Press any key to continue . . ."; echo` **Oh my gosh... I've done it! I've made Windose!**

Comment: This solution (incl. ;echo) is more elegant since it brings the terminal back to a fresh new line. just my 2 cents

Answer (score 20):

As @cas wrote in a comment, you really should use `less` for this.  If the changelog is more than one page, you really want a pager anyway.

You normally want to consult the `PAGER` environment variable instead of just calling `less`:

```
${PAGER:-less} changelog
```

will use `$PAGER` if it is set and `less` otherwise.

Comment: Thank you my changelog is not that long, its less than half of iPhone screen (I'm doing script on iPhone)